# Where can I download WSS & MOSS 2007 WITHOUT Service Pack 2?

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, upgrade

I am looking for WSS & MOSS 2007 installation files WITHOUT Service Pack 2. Everything I have found so far includes SP2.

Is it possible to somehow remove SP2 from the download?

Why:
I have a production instance of MOSS 2007 with Service Pack 1. In order to migrate content to SharePoint Server 2010, you first have to upgrade 2007 to Service Pack 2. I am getting an error installing SP2 because someone deleted the C:\Windows\Installer folder and apparently those files are needed for the service pack.

If I could install MOSS 2007 rtm or sp1 on a test server, I could copy the missing folder to production OR use the test server for the upgrade.

I am looking for the 32 bit versions. To be verbose, I am looking for the x86 version of Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Trial for Standard and Enterprise and x86 version of Windows SharePoint Services 3.0.

Update:

SharePoint Server 2007 Trial Version for Developers:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4325

Windows SharePoint Services 3.0:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14117

Comment: Is your update the answer ? If yes, write an answer, not an update. This will allow you to flag your question answered

Comment: I will. It says I can't self-answer a question within 8 hours. I'm also not 100% sure the SharePoint Trial Version doesn't include service pack 2. I was going to install it and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Server 2007 Trial Version for Developers
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4325

Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14117

I installed both of these and confirmed I am at version 12.0.0.4518, which is MOSS 2007/WSS 3.0 RTM.